# I am getting method ambigous error for below code

Tags: java, methods

My question is related to method ambiguity .

Here code 1 print "first" without ambigity error even though foo(int i , int s) defined with having same arguments two times .it picks first method and execute it successfully , but if I modify both methods argument as foo(int i,long s) and foo(long i,int d) then it gives below error ,So my question is Why it is showing ambiguty here if in first case it has worked sucessfully -

ERROR-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method foo(int, long) is ambiguous for the type StaticFunc

    at StaticFunc.main(StaticFunc.java:6)
```

**Code 1**

```
public class StaticFunc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(10, 100);
    }

    public static void foo(int i, int s) {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    public static void foo(int i, int d) {
        System.out.println("Second");
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
public class StaticFunc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(10, 100);
    }

    public static void foo(int i,long s) {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    public static void  foo(long i,int d) {
        System.out.println("Second");
    }
}
```

I expect ouput as first , but getting error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method foo(int, long) is ambiguous for the type StaticFunc

    at StaticFunc.main(StaticFunc.java:6)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call the method like this:

```
foo(10,100l);

foo(10l,100);
```

I guess the error is related to primitive types of Java, the compiler doesn`t know what method choose because of both parameters are int.

Specifieing which are long, the compiler founds which one to call

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your first code got executed, how ever it is expected that you should have got - error: method foo(int,int) is already defined in class StaticFunc

While the output of second code is expected, since compiler does not know which method to call.Java compiler doesn't consider any of them to be more specific, hence the method ambiguous call error.

If you want to execute second code you can call the function with long parameter using `foo(10L,100)`

Answer (score 0):

In java, you can tell the compiler what kind of numbers do you have, if you look at the signatures, you have:

```
public static void  foo(int i,long s) 
public static void  foo(long i,int d)
```

You have an overload of the method, that's ok, but now, when you use the methods, you have diferent types as arguments of `foo`

You can do this in several ways:

```
int x  = 10;
long y = 100;

foo(x, y)
```

or just

```
foo(10, 100L)
```

the `L` means your number is of type `long`, the same can be done with `10.02F` meaning `float`, or `10.05D` meaning `double`
IS better to use capitalized letter so the is no missunderstanding between `1l` (looks like eleven) and `1L`, (1 long)